# Merging two JQuery functions to get desired results

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

I have two functions for single multiple dropdown box. First function is to select multiple options even with `single click` or with `ctrl+click` and my second function is to sum up the `data` attribute to get the total of all listed options. I am done trying with several tries and not been able to get my desired result.

As per the https://jsfiddle.net/w4tnv3zm/ demo, on a single click or even with ctrl click to select multiple options, the sum of `data attribute` should work/display in the div id.

```
<select class="form-control select-multi" name="grp[]" id="grp" multiple="multiple" required="">
    <option value="1" data-cntotal="1100">1 group (1100 Nos.)</option>
    <option value="2" data-cntotal="857">2 group (857 Nos.)</option>
    <option value="3" data-cntotal="998">3 group (998 Nos.)</option>
    <option value="4" data-cntotal="823">4 group (823 Nos.)</option>
    <option value="5" data-cntotal="959">5 group (959 Nos.)</option>
</select>
<span id="total_box" class='help-block text-purple text-bold'></span><br><span id="mmcount" class='help-block text-blue text-bold'></span>
```

My JS code

```
$('.select-multi').each(function() {
    var select = $(this),
        values = {};
    $('option', select).each(function(i, option) {
        values[option.value] = option.selected;
    }).click(function(event) {
        values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
        $('option', select).each(function(i, option) {
            option.selected = values[option.value];
        });
        var tcount = $(".select-multi :selected").length;
        $("#mmcount").text(tcount + " total group(s) selected.")
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grp").change(function() {
        $("#total_box").empty();
        var sum = 0,
            price;
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("data-cntotal")) {
                price = $(this).data("cntotal");
                sum += price;
            }
        });
        $("#total_box").text("Total Mobile Numbers selected: " + sum);
    });
});
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another method.

```
$('#grp option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#total_box").empty();
    var sum = 0, tcount = 0, price;
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    $('#grp').find("option:selected").each(function() {
            //console.log($(this).val())
        price = $(this).data("cntotal");
        sum += price;
        tcount++;
    });
    $("#total_box").text("Total Mobile Numbers selected: " +sum);
    $("#mmcount").text(tcount + " total group(s) selected.")
 })
```

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/0oL9xoqj/

Comment: Awww.. This is perfectly working on my live site too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that the change event will trigger before your select-multi event.  Also, the way you set up your project, you don't even need the change event, your select-multi event reset the selected option (which is the change) and re-apply it when previous item and is triggered on every click.  Just move your count where you set your select-multi click event.  see this https://jsfiddle.net/w4tnv3zm/4/

```
$('.select-multi').each(function(){

    var select = $(this), values = {};    
    $('option',select).each(function(i, option){
        values[option.value] = option.selected;        
    }).click(function(event){        
        values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
        $('option',select).each(function(i, option){            
            option.selected = values[option.value];        
        });
        var tcount = $(".select-multi :selected").length;
        $("#mmcount").text(tcount + " total group(s) selected.")        
        var sum=0
        $('option:selected').each(function(i,d){
            sum += $(d).data("cntotal")
        })
        $("#total_box").text("Total Mobile Numbers selected: " +sum);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {      

});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your time and efforts to help me out. Appreciate it.

Comment: hi @chungtinhlakho, on jsfiddle its working fine, on my live site, the sum is showing as `NaN`, what could be the reason?

Comment: make sure var sum is var sum=0

Comment: Yes, it is, I just copy pasted the same code from jsfiddle, but anyway, the other method also working fine as posted by djay. So going with it as of now. Sorry for not accepting your answer.